# shell script rename multi files and remove single quote

Tags: shell, sed

im trying to apply this logic ,  using sed to replace and rename

any tips please

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/san -type f -name "*'*" > /tmp/output | while read file
do
      rename all files by deleting single quote from the name 

done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find` with `xargs` and `rename` (if your system has the `util-linux` package installed).

```
find /home/san -type f -name "*'*" -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 rename "'" ""
```

With 'sed' as specified, you can use command substitution:

```
find "/home/san" -type f -name "*'*" | while IFS= read -r file
do
  # we need to avoid replacing characters in the path to the file,
  # so split it into dirname and filename.
  DIRNAME=$(dirname "$file")
  FILENAME=$(basename "$file")
  NEWNAME=$(sed "s/'//g" <<< "$FILENAME")
  mv -v --no-clobber "$file" "$DIRNAME/$NEWNAME" || echo "$DIRNAME/$NEWNAME already exists, not overwriting."
done
```

`--no-clobber` ensures that if there is a file with same name, it is not overwritten. "-v" just shows you what is being done, you can remove the "-v" if you don't care about seeing that.

Comment: one addition if i remove all special chars from the name ? not only single quotes

Comment: I've edited the post since your comment, with a 'sed' based solution. `rename` doesn't support regular-expressions, but sed does. Using character classes, you could specify multiple characters to replace with "", as in `['!#\$^&*]` rather than `'`. Installing `renamexm` is also an option, as it supports regular expressions and could replace `rename` in the command I gave before. Either way, you would have to get a basic understanding of regular expressions.  Alternatively, you could use a GUI-based batch-renamer like `gprename` or `pyrenamer` that has options for removing special characters.

Comment: For safety, should use `while IFS= read -r file`. For example, if a filename *begins* with whitespace, the plain `while read file` will lose it.

Comment: i was trying sed option but no luck it dosnt work and no error in output file , in order its already catched files with single quote in output

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan: I realized that was due to the `> /tmp/output` that I foolishly copied from your original post. It should be fixed now. I'm also working on a version that is more robust (won't fail if the path to the file contains one of the characters being replaced).

Comment: @MarcoDonJuan: Okay, the answer is now updated with the full, tested sed-based solution.

Comment: perfect answer , now its executed smoothly ,

Comment: Why not use bash string function instead of `sed`? `mv "$file" "${file//"'"/}"`

Comment: @Jaypal: That's good to know, but I'm not going to update my answer -- I prefer to write code that won't break even if you run it in something as minimal as `dash` [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell)